# chi-square test when data is nested

Tags: chi-squared-test

I'm reviewing a paper that uses a chi-square test on data that is nested (in other words, there is nesting of observations within individuals). My understanding is that an assumption of chi-square test is that observations are independent, and that if there is clustering within individuals, that this is not the case. is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which chi-square test the paper uses.  There are lots of tests with $\chi^2$ null distributions. Some of them are appropriate for clustered data. However, if they're using the straightforward (Pearson) $X^2$ test for independence or homogeneity, then it does assume independence and there will be a problem if data are clustered.

Comment: wonderful. thank you!

Comment: I know this isn't in the question but do you know of a good alternative to Pearson chi-square when the data are nested? The only thing that comes to my mind is logistic/multinomial multilevel models...